# why my input type doesn't accept emoji?

Tags: emoji, mail-sender

emoji is a new concept , so campanies would send their mail with an emoji pictures in the subject , i have my application that send normaly mails but it doesn't support emoji pictures , i looked around and i found that gmail did support it, here is my code:

```
 <label class="form-label-up">Subject</label>
 <input id="subject-input-value" class="form-textbox form-textbox-small"type="text" name="text_3681">
```

in fact when i copy paste my emoji symbol ,and click save,it disappeared .i will appreciate any help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: actually it is about programming, i ask for encoding a non printable caracters in the case of emoji .